# Xcode doesn't recognize property after converting existing Swift 1.2 code to 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift2

I converted some Swift 1.2 code to Swift 2.0 using Xcode.
The converted class has these two properties defined :

```
 public var onSubmit: ((value: AnyObject...) -> Void)!
 public var onCancel: (() -> Void)!
```

I am using an object of this class in Objective-C. But, I am unable to access the onSubmit property. I get an error "Property 'onSubmit' not found on object of type 'BMInputBox *'"

**Can't do this:**

```
anInputBox.onSubmit = ^(NSArray *values) {
    NSLog(@"%@", values);
};
```

But, strangely I can access onCancel

**Can to this:**

```
anInputBox.onCancel = nil;
```

Any idea what may be the problem here or how to fix this?

I have imported the `"MyProject-Swift.h"` header.
The header doesn't have the onSubmit property defined either. While it does have one for onCancel:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^ __null_unspecified onCancel)(void);
```

The code was working fine before converting to Swift 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your onSubmit closure to receive an array parameter in swift

```
public var onSubmit: ((value: [AnyObject]) -> Void)!
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Can you please provide an explanation. I'm new to Swift. Why was this working before and not now?

Comment: @Rage maybe in 1.2 swift variadic paramters is implicitly converted to array. Variadic paramter function is not interchangeable between swift and objc actually